# ValueError: NaTType does not support timetuple when converting a dataframe to dictionary using to_dict('records')

Tags: pandas, flask, google-bigquery, valueerror

I'm running this flask app

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import json

import pandas as pd

# Create the app object
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources= {r"/*": {'origins' : "*"}})


# importing function for calculations
from Record_Matching import Matching


@app.route("/query", methods = ['get'])
@cross_origin()
def query():

    # service_account_creds = request.json
    query1 = request.args.get('query1', type = str)
    query2 = request.args.get('query2', type = str)
    querycolumns = request.args.get('querycolumns')
    
    project_id = request.args.get('project_id', type = str)
    service_account_creds = request.args.get('service_account')
    SS = request.args.get('SS', type = float)
    TT = request.args.get('TT', type = float)
    result = Matching(query1,query2, SS,TT, service_account_creds, project_id, querycolumns)

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", port=8080, debug=True)
```

and I'm importing the matching function from this python scripts

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import recordlinkage
from recordlinkage.preprocessing import phonetic
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import uuid
from uuid import uuid4
import random
import string
import json
import ast



# Results to data frame function
def gcp2df(sql, client):
    query = client.query(sql)
    results = query.result()
    return results.to_dataframe()
# Exporting df to bigquery - table parameter example: "dataset.tablename"
# def insert(df, table):
#     client = bigquery.Client()
#     job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(write_disposition=bigquery.job.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
#     return client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table, job_config = job_config)

def pair(df1, df2, TT, querycolumns):
    
    # function to take pair from list and compare:
    L = querycolumns
    l=len(querycolumns)
    p1=0
    p2=1

    # To generate phonetics we  need to make sure all names are in english. 
    # thus we'll replace non-english words by random english strings
    df1[L[p1]] = df1[L[p1]].astype(str)
    df2[L[p2]] = df2[L[p2]].astype(str)
    for i in range(0,len(df1)):
        if df1[L[p1]][i].isascii() == False:
            df1[L[p1]][i] = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=5))

    for i in range(0,len(df2)):
        if df2[L[p2]][i].isascii() == False:
            df2[L[p2]][i] = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=5))


    compare = recordlinkage.Compare()
    df1["phonetic_given_name"] = phonetic(df1[L[p1]], "soundex")
    df2["phonetic_given_name"] = phonetic(df2[L[p2]], "soundex")
    df1["initials"] = (df1[L[p1]].str[0]  + df1[L[p1]].str[-1])
    df2["initials"] = (df2[L[p2]].str[0]  + df2[L[p2]].str[-1])
    indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
    indexer.block('initials')
    candidate_links = indexer.index(df1, df2)
    compare.exact('phonetic_given_name', 'phonetic_given_name', label="phonetic_given_name")
    # O(n) a function that uses two pointers to track consecutive pairs for the input list  
    while p2 <=l:
        compare.string(L[p1], L[p2], method='jarowinkler',threshold = TT, label=L[p1])
        p1+=2
        p2+=2
    features = compare.compute(candidate_links,df1, df2)
    return features




def Matching(query1,query2, SS,TT, service_account_creds, project_id, querycolumns):

    service_account_creds = ast.literal_eval(service_account_creds)
    credentials = service_account.Credentials(service_account_creds, service_account_creds['client_email'], 
                                            service_account_creds['token_uri'])
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    client = bigquery.Client( project = project_id)


    SS=int(SS)
    TT=float(TT)

    df1 = gcp2df("""{}""".format(query1), client)
    df2 = gcp2df("""{}""".format(query2), client)

    querycolumns = json.loads(querycolumns)
    querycolumns = list(querycolumns.values())
    features = pair(df1, df2, TT, querycolumns)
    features['Similarity_score'] = features.sum(axis=1)
    features = features[features['Similarity_score']>=SS].reset_index()
    final =  features[['level_0', 'level_1']]
    final.rename(columns= {'level_0':'df1_index', 'level_1':'df2_index'}, inplace= True)
    final['Unique_ID'] = [uuid.uuid4() for _ in range(len(final.index))]
    final['Unique_ID'] = final['Unique_ID'].astype(str)
    final['Similarity_Score'] = SS
    final_duplicates = final['df1_index'].value_counts().max()
    # insert(final,"test-ahmed-project.Record_Linkage.Matching_Indices")
    message = "Mission accomplished!, your highest number of duplicates is  " + str(final_duplicates) 
    return {'message':message,'final':final.to_dict('records'), 'df1':df1.to_dict('records')}
```

I'm not sure why when I return df1 as a dictionary it shows ValueError error when I try to to use the function from flask app, but when I run it in a jupytor notebook using the same dataframe that I'm taking from bigquery, it works just fine, so why does it not work on the flask app?

I tried to_dict('record') to convert a dataframe to a dictionary,

it looking online many resources suggest the error exists because the data contains missing values, but it shouldn't be a problem because when I try converting the same dataframe to dictionary in jupyter notebook it works just fine.

Comment: Hi @ahmad Abdallah, can you clarify your requirement and where are you running your flask app?